# pyQT динамический QLabel

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

Как можно в бесконечном цикле изменять `QLabel`? Т.е. надо посекундно обновлять `QLabel`, но если впихнуть в код такой цикл, `QTGui` не иницализируется.

Answer (score 1):

После каждого обновления вызывайте [`processEvents`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents)

Answer (score 1):

Вместо бесконечного цикла можно запустить `QTimer`, который и будет обновлять `QLabel`, например:

```
...

app = QApplication([])

mw = QLabel("0")
mw.show()

timer = QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(lambda: mw.setText(str(int(mw.text()) + 1)))
timer.start(1000)

app.exec()
```

Answer (score 0):

во первых, сначала инициируй и выведи окно с твоим QLabel и только после этого в отдельной функции реализуй изменение QLabel.

Краткий пример:

```
 app = QApplication([]);

 wnd = Window();

 wnd.show();  
 wnd.labelProgress();

 app.exec_();
```